# How to Interpret "Levels" in Random Forest using R/Rattle

Tags: r, rattle

I am brand new at using R/Rattle and am having difficulty understanding how to  interpret the last line of this code output. Here is the function call along with it's output:

```
> head(weatherRF$model$predicted, 10)
336 342 94 304 227 173 265 44 230 245
No No No No No No No No No No 
Levels: No Yes
```

This code is implementing a weather data set in which we are trying to get predictions for "RainTomorrow". I understand that this function calls for the predictions for the first 10 observations of the data set. What I do NOT understand is what the last line ("Levels: No Yes") means in the output.

Comment: Seems to me a factor, although I don't know what is rattle library do, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information

Answer (score 1):

It's called a factor variable.

That is the list of permitted values of the factor, here the values No and Yes are permitted.